# org.hibernate.HibernateException: PostgreSQL supports only one REF_CURSOR parameter, but multiple were registered

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

In my PostgreSQL database I have a function `my_cursors()` that returns 2 cursors. I need to call it through a Java app, so I used Hibernate ORM, but I am getting the error in the title.

Question: Is there another way to call `my_cursors()`, so that it returns only a single cursor?

Below is my junit test:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Test
@Transactional("myTransactionManager")
public void call_my_cursors() {
    
    StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("my_cursors")
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Object.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, Object.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
    List<Object> obj = (List) query.getResultList();
    assertNotNull(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom Dialect and override `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect#getCallableStatementSupport` to return a custom implementation similar to `org.hibernate.procedure.internal.PostgresCallableStatementSupport` that doesn't do this check. The question is, since when does PostgreSQL support multiple REF_CURSOR? I don't think this was done for fun, so it would be nice to know which version of PostgreSQL starts to support this so that this can be updated in Hibernate.